# Really annoying ads "recommended for you" visible on all tabs of all browser

Tags: windows-7, browser, virus, advertisements

I'm having this annoying problem: a big ad (named "Recommended for you") that appears on **random sites** (even here) and remains opened in every tab of **all my browsers** (Opera, IE).

My OS is Windows 7 Home Premium x64 and i'm using Opera 11.62, IE 9, and did a full scan with MSE. Seems not happening in Firefox. Reinstalling Opera didn't fix the problem.

I can't find how to remove it. I don't even know the name of this. I'll post an image and thanks for helping.

**UPDATE**: i've changed the image with one from this site. A full scan with Spybot Search & Destroy, Malwayrebte and MSE found nothing.

**UPDATE2**: found what's the ad is, http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/topic449943.html but my hosts file is clean.

[image]

Comment: You want advice with virus removal, and you didn't even list your OS?

Comment: He says "...(Opera, IE)" and that gives it away.

Comment: @ultrasawblade: [Not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_for_Mac)  [really.](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=25)  And version is important also.

Comment: @BenVoigt specifications added, thanks for helping.

Comment: @Gremo: Just to double-check, you're using Opera's own rendering engine, and not "IE Tab" or [similar]?

Comment: @BenVoigt Opera own rendering engine. I'll use IE only for those sites that just don't render properly on Opera.

Comment: Revise your '**UPDATE 2**' as your hosts file WASN'T clear as per your answer below! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. It was the `hosts` file hijacked. I started the system using a bootable media (MSDaRT 6.5) and removed the unwanted entries from that file:

```
68.168.222.226 www.google-analytics.com
68.168.222.226 ad-emea.doubleclick.net
68.168.222.226 www.statcounter.com
108.163.215.51 www.google-analytics.com
108.163.215.51 ad-emea.doubleclick.net
108.163.215.51 www.statcounter.com
```

Answer (score 4):

1) Run windows update, get all the updates you can. If you aren't getting updates you have a bigger problem on your hand.

2) Download Spybot Search & Destroy, Malwayrebtes and Microsoft Security Essentials. Update all of them, and get them to scan your system and clean out everything they find.

Comment: Thanks for helping. My system is up to date, last updates are dated 24 apr 2012. I'll go for Spybot.

Comment: @Gremo I recommend trying all of them, they do similar but different things, and all are free.

Comment: Unfortunately Spybot didn't find anything. I'm running a full scan with Malwayrebtes right now.

Comment: In IE9 enable activex filtering (so that it's on) - do the ads go away? Go to the proxy settings on your browsers - is something filled in there? (If there is and that's not normal, get rid of it) This almost sounds like that DNS thing people were talking about recently.

Comment: Also Malwayrebtes dind't find anything. I'm stuck now. No proxy setted and DNS are auto.

Comment: @Gremo and microsoft security essentials? It's odd that the others didn't pick this one up, this kind of stuff is their whole business.

Comment: @BloodyIron i used MSE in the first place, full scan (took hours to complete) and nothing was found. I'll go for a format tomorrow if i'll not solve this, but anyway thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has a plugin called AdBlock Plus that works very well.

Install Firefox.
Choose menu > Addons.
Search and install AdBlock Plus.

Then you'll be able to download lists of adservers to block, or manually block ads by:
Right click on the image.
Choose AdBlock: Block image...
 --or--
Mouse over a flash object and click on the block tab that appears.

Comment: Why i'm supposed to be force to user Firefox? I'm using Opera and i like it. Plus i'm already using urfilter.ini (that's Opera adblock).